# How to get data attribute from angular FormControl

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a form like bellow

```
                      <form #f="ngForm">
                           <div >
                                <label 
                                      
                                       for="governmentalPosition">
                                    MasterAgentInCashDeskGovernmentalPosition
                                </label>
                                <input 
                                       id="governmentalPosition"
                                       name="governmentalPosition"
                                       [attr.data-localization]="'MasterAgentInCashDeskGovernmentalPosition'"
                                       type="text"
                                       required
                                       pInputText
                                       maxlength="500"
                                       #governmentalPositionControl="ngModel"                                       [(ngModel)]="model.governmentalPosition">
                               
                            </div> 
                     </form>
                    
                     <button   type="button" (click)="save(f)" >
                           submit
                     </button>
```

and I use this ts or js method

```
  save(f: NgForm) {
             Object.keys(f.controls).forEach(controlName => {
                let rr = f.controls[controlName].errors;
                //this how I can get the attr.data-localization
            }
        }
```

How I can get data attribute in ts file or js file in angular app

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `data attribute` using different approach:

**Angular way:**

```
@ViewChild('governmentalPositionControl') input: ElementRef; 
//...
const dataValue = this.input.nativeElement.getAttribute("data-localization"); //--> get the data attribute
```

**Pure javascript**:

```
const input = document.querySelector("#governmentalPosition"); //--> get the element
const dataValue = input.getAttribute("data-localization"); //--> get the data attribute
```

Comment: I need to get data-attribute from just FormControl, because I send FormControl to another service and there we use data-attribute for some work with form. Thank you for your effort to resolve the issue.

Comment: Other solution is after create the form, you can add this extra property,     this.form.controls['controlName']["data-localization"] = "value"; and get the value like this this.form.controls['controlName']["data-localization"]